# Qui seront les modérateurs ? Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion

<sup>(English below)</sup>

Une des [7 questions essentielles de tout site en bêta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) : qui seront les modérateurs du site ? Pour la durée de la bêta, c'est le personnel de Stack Exchange qui nomme des modérateurs, en général trois. Après la fin de la bêta, les modérateurs seront élus par la communauté. Cette question est un appel à nominations et canditatures pour être modérateur pendant la bêta.

Les **qualités recherchées** chez un modérateur sont :

- participer activement au site, ce qui se traduit en général par une réputation élevée ;
- porter un intérêt au site méta ;
- monter l'exemple, notamment en termes de patience et de respect pour les autres membres de la communauté dans tous leurs écrits ;
- toutes ces qualités intangibles décrites dans [*la théorie de la modération*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Les points suivants sont des plus :

- participer activement à la fois au site principal et au site méta, c'est-à-dire faire preuve à la fois d'expertise dans le domaine et d'intérêt pour la construction de la communauté ;
- avoir participé à la définition du site sur [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), ou avoir fait connaître le site par des réseaux sociaux ou des blogs ;
- de manière générale, avoir déjà montré un intérêt sinon une capacité à promouvoir la communauté.

Donc, qui seront les modérateurs ? Même si c'est le personnel de Stack Exchange qui décidera, les nominations permettent de jauger l'opinion de la communauté. Merci de répondre ainsi :

- Une réponse par candidat, et un candidat par réponse. Inclure un lien vers le profil du candidat sur le site principal et son site sur le site méta.
- Si un candidat est nominé, il peut répondre pour dire qu'il accepte ou décline.
- Les **candidatures spontanées** (auto-nominations) sont autorisées et même encouragées.

Les candidats sont invités à lire [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Les modérateurs nommés devront signifier leur adhésion à [l'accord pour les modérateurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement). Étant donné la spécificité de ce site d'être bilingue, il vaudrait mieux que les modérateurs puissent converser en anglais et en français.

---

One of the [7 essential meta questions of every beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/): who should our moderators be? When the site launches, moderators will be elected by the community. For the duration of the beta, Stack Exchange staff will designate moderators (usually 3). This thread exists to nominate candidates (nominations are not binding in any way).

Please read [Moderators pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) to see what is expected of moderators. Reply here with nominations or candidacies.

The **qualities sought** in a moderator are:

- To participate actively in the site, which generally results in a higher reputation;
- To have an interest in the meta site;
- To set an example, notably in terms of patience and respect for the other members of the community, in all their communications;
- All the intangible qualities described in the [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Furthermore, the following qualities are desirable:

- To participate actively both on the main site and on the meta site, ie. show both expertise in the domain, and interest in the building of the community;
- To have participated in the definition of the site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), or to have helped promote the site via social networking and/or blogs;
- Generally, to have already shown an interest in, if not a capacity to, promote the community.

So, who should the moderators be?  Even if it's the Stack Exchange staff who will decide, the nominations will help to gauge the opinion of the community.  Please respond in this way:

- One response/answer per candidate, and one candidate per response/answer.  Include a link to their profile on the main site, and on the meta site.
- If a candidate is nominated, they may respond to say whether they accept or decline the nomination.
- Self-nominations are allowed and even encouraged.

The candidates are invited to read *[A Theory Of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)*.  The moderators named have to review and accept the [Moderator Agreement](https://french.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement).  Given the bilingual nature of this site, it would be preferable that the moderators be able to converse in English and in French.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Stack Exchange staff would pick the pro temp mods themselves.

Comment: I have one suggestion to make: I think it would be a good thing if at least one of the moderators was a non-native French speaker. The site currently has a nice language balance and a real open-mindedness, which I appreciate. I think having a non-native speaker would help us keep an ear out for this matter.   
                              Un seul commentaire de ma part (pour l'instant) : je pense qu'il serait bon d'avoir (au moins) un modérateur dont le français ne soit pas la langue maternelle, pour nous aider à conserver l'équilibre présent (et bénéfique) sur le site aujourd'hui.

Comment: @Joubarc, if I understand correctly, they choose but ask for suggestion (see [Moderators pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/))

Comment: Well two choices seem very obvious anyway.

Comment: And for the others... I would tend to avoid people whose highest rep is here on FL&U, as it may indicate they're not familiar enough with SE sites in general; but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Joubarc We pick them ourselves, but pointing out very strong users can be extremely helpful if we happen to overlook a candidate. As such, it's an aide to the selection process.

Comment: To whomever set all the answers as CW: if the point is that the posters may vote on their own nominees, it's a great idea, but alas, it doesn't work.

Comment: @joubarc: I would add a third choice, yourself, if you are willing to serve.

Answer (score 12):

I nominate [F'x](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/19/fx?tab=accounts) as moderator pro tempore ([meta account](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19/fx)).

F'x has demonstrated a great commitment to the beta already, earning both a solid reputation and an impressive number of badges in a very short time.

In addition, his knowledge of other Stack Exchange sites and in particular of the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3479/fx) one should prove very useful.

Comment: If the community and the SE team feel I would be a good fit, I will accept this responsibility. I considered nominating myself, but Joubarc was quicker than I could make my mind. I envision moderation as something to be done with a rather light touch, especially in the beginning where the community has to define and structure itself. I applaud the effort that Gilles did here on meta to start these important discussions, and I think this is crucial for now.

Comment: Agreed on Gilles being very active leading discussions here on meta - I forgot to mention that, but it does seem vital at this stage.

Comment: Seems someone ought to get his diamond soon. (And I got a "nice answer" badge, yay.)

Answer (score 10):

I nominate [Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles?tab=accounts) as moderator pro tempore ([meta account](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles)).

Gilles has shown he his dedicated to make this site work and has logically earned the highest reputation so far.

Also, Gilles is [very active](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) on other Stack Exchange sites, and is already moderator on the [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles) beta. As such, he knows the ropes, and how a good SE site should grow to maturity.

Comment: I accept the nomination. If chosen, I will perform the job fairly, irrespective of whether the balance of languages we choose for the site agrees with my preferences. We are off to a very good start, and I hope the site can become a reference for questions about the French language. ❚ J'accepte la nomination. Si je suis choisi, je remplirai mon rôle sérieusement, quel que soit l'équilibre entre l'anglais et le français finalement retenu par notre communauté. Le site a très bien démarré, et j'espère qu'il pourra devenir une référence pour les questions sur la langue française.

Comment: Cinq ans plus tard...."pro tempore" indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe Jez ([meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/jez), [main](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/8/jez)) (as proposer of the site) should have a look-in too.

Comment: I would be OK with being a pro temp mod if it were deemed appropriate.

Comment: One response/answer per candidate, and one candidate per response/answer

Comment: @Mvy, well here I'm only proposing one (new) candidate, and I'm not answering as a candidate (that's the other answer). I think I'm respecting the spirit of the law.

Comment: It's confusing. First part (agreeing should) be comment and upvote on the other answers.

Comment: Well let's just unconfuse that, it's rather easy - the proposal here is Jez. There, done.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mind having a shot at being a moderator [myself](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/40) ([meta profile](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40/benjol)), to be honest. I was the proposer of the '[other half](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation)' of this site :)

And I could be the token non-native that F'x suggested.

*Je sais que la curiosité est un vilain défaut, mais j'aimerais aussi voir une fois à quoi ressemblent ces mystérieux 'outils modérateurs'* :)

Comment: Moderation tools are boring so far ;-) Seriously, very valid point that you were the one proposing the translation part... which begs the question: why don't you ask some of the example questions from there on FL&U? I would love to see how people here would translate "thee" or "thou" (_Thee for thou, and thou for thee..._)

Comment: @Joubarc, moderation tools are also boring on SO. You are overflowed by things on tags you don't follow.

Comment: @Joubarc, well I [did](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/400/nuancier-des-grossieretes) ask the [first one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation/2082#2082). And [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation/2099#2099) one [too](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23/est-ce-que-ca-est-si-grave-que-ca). I suppose I could ask some others, but I hesitate to ask ones which weren't 'mine' originally. And I didn't want to be  too 'pushy' about translation

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed while browsing them that some were familiar after all. Fair enough to ask only yours, I guess; but if you feel some of the others are good and their original poster isn't much active here... Well, why not. As for being pushy about translations, I think it's quite clear now that they're going to be an integral part of FL&U, and we have quite a lot already.

Comment: @Benjol you're more than a token to us! :)

Comment: @Fx, aw shucks, now you're making me blush :)

Comment: @Benjol Oh please, ask a question about *thou* :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to nominate [Dave](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/97/dave) ([meta account](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/97/dave)). He is (from what I can tell) perfectly bilingual in French and English, and has been an active contributor to the site.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that Dave is a moderator on the Japanese Language & Usage beta.